# Mailer preview: Undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie Rails programmer and trying to set up a mailer preview but when visiting the preview on the server I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `email' for #<InvitationMailerPreview:0x000000051a77c8>
```

In test/mailers/previews/invitation_mailer_preview.rb I have the method below. The error message points to the `invitation =` line. The Invitation table does contain a column named `email`.

```
def invitation
  invitation = Invitation.where(email != nil).first
  InvitationMailer.invitation_verified(invitation)
end
```

In app/mailers/invitation_mailer.rb (shortened for this post):

```
def invitation(invitation)
  @invitation = invitation
  mail to: invitation.invitee.email
end
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and what causes this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The where clause needs to be passed a hash.

To find the invitations that have a `nil` email:

```
invitation = Invitation.where(email: nil).first
```

To find the invitations that does **not** have a `nil` email:

```
invitation = Invitation.where.not(email: nil).first
```

which is equivalent to:

```
invitation = Invitation.where('email IS NOT NULL').first
```

Answer (score 0):

`Invitation.where(email != nil)` is invalid. You should change it to: `Invitation.where.not(email: nil)`